# Bridge between Physical Ethernet and VLAN possible?

Tags: network-interface, bridge, vlan

I would like to do something but I dont know if its possible.

I have router edgemax edgepoe4:

- Eth1 : receive a tagged vlan 10
- Eth2 (No TAG traffic) : no vlan define, DHCP server defines to connect all my lans devices

I would like to make a communicaton betweend Eth1.10 and Eth2 (for example my pc on Eth2 can access a NAS which is located on Eth1.10) without creating a vlan on Eth2. I imagine that a bridge can do that but from what i read i only see bridges between Vlans or Ethernet, i havent find yet a link between a vlan and an ethernet.

How can I do that ? Is the creation of the Vlan is the only way ?

Another thing : is it possible to assign an IP address from my eth2 DHCP server to a device in Eth1.10 ?

Comment: you have two different questions, you should make two different posts.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to get the subnet on eth1.10 to communicate with the subnet on eth2. You can just use intervlan routing to do that.

In IPv4, VLAN traffic isn't aware that it's contained to a VLAN, it only knows its collision domain, and the default gateway. By telling the router to route the traffic between the specified subnets, then the VLAN traffic will traverse into non-VLAN collision domains, if you configure it to do so.

*As for your second question:  once you get the intervlan routing working, DCHP broadcasts do traverse collision domains, so yes it is possible to do so.*